# Trying to get this for loop to work?

Tags: c, for-loop

I just started to learn C so the answer is probably incredibly obvious but when I run this code the number 0 just keeps repeating in an infinite loop.  I'm trying to print x from 0 to 1 in increments of .05.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double x;


for( x = 0; x <= 1; x+.05 )
{

   printf("%d\n", x );
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for( x = 0; x <= 1; x += .05 )
```

seems like your not writing the changed x value to x..... If you know what I mean :D
`x++` is the same as `x+=1`
`x+.05` doesn't modify x's value, thus x will always be 0 and result in a infinite loop...

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
for( x = 0; x <= 1; x+=0.05 )
{
   printf("%f\n", x );
}
```

You'll want to change to the **+=** sign and change the **d** to an **f**.

- **d** is for decimal integers
- **f** is for floating point numbers

Answer (score 0):

You want the addition and assignment compound operator, which is `+=`, not just `+`.

```
for( x = 0; x <= 1; x+=.05 )
```

Currently the result of your expression is `x + 5`, and its result is not used, resulting in your loop's condition never being false.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in your for loop to 
    `for( x = 0; x <= 1; x += .05 )`

Note that 
    `x += .05` 
Is equivalent to typing 
    `x = x + .05` 
which is what you really want since the goal is to update the value of x.